# SQL server update statement does not working

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-update

I tired to execute the below simple update statement in SQL server. Once I execute the statement, it shows `2 rows updated`, but the data in the table is not yet updated and the `IsTransferred` column still remains as `1`. The column is bit type and does not accept nulls. Its default value is set to 0.

```
update SellToBuyTariffs set IsTransferred=0 where Description='AUTOSELLTOBUY'
```

Kindly help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: either you are running the statement in one DB and looking at the table in another DB, or that column is calculate or overwritten by something else automatically. (such as a trigger)

Comment: I am looking in a single DB only and no triggers have been created on that table. I have tried from another person's desk also. Still facing the same issue. and moreover this exists only for the mentioned column and not for the remaining column.

Comment: Are you sure the column is not defined as 'Computed'?

Comment: yes... its not defined as 'Computed'.

Comment: This is strange!! What query are you using to see whether the data got changed or not? Can you please share that select query? And is there any other process which is doing any kind of insertions or updations to the same table in between?